# Cannot resolve symbol error in Java class Android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Whenever I type in class to test my java code some red curly lines appear in toolbox and android studio code and it gives symbol error for every word typed in.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, invalidate caches , rebuild e.t.c but none of them worked.

**code**

```java
package com.example.lib;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

**Error code**

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'String'
Cannot resolve symbol 'System'
```

**Image**

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NuSj.jpg)

Comment: Might be a subsequent problem because of the missing space between `static` and `void`.

Comment: I suggest learning java separately from Android to start

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using copy/paste to copy the code from your IDE into Stack Overflow - the code in your question doesn't have the same problem as the code in your screenshot. This would have been clearer if you hadn't also skipped the first error shown in your IDE ("Cannot resolve symbol staticvoid").

Answer (score 3):

Try to add the missing space between `static` and `void`.